# No wifi connection Ubuntu 15.10

Tags: wireless

I can not connect internet due wifi despite that the upper panel show the computer is connected due wifi. Under settings / software and updates / other drivers there is no wifi driver showed.

[If have found these details also about my computer/Ubuntu](http://play48.com/gratisupload/userprofiles/MTPaUot08H/wireless%2Epdf)

Comment: refer [link]http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2203079

Answer (score 0):

If you install Ubuntu, you probably have the copy of the ISO image of it. Otherwise, download the ISO **with the same build** of Ubuntu you are using. **Copy** it in a flashdrive or just save it somewhere where you can access it when you are using Ubuntu. Open **Software and Updates** in Ubuntu. Then on the driver's tab. Click the wireless driver you want to use. Then that's it.